# A generic omniauth provider/strategy for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I implemented an omniauth strategy as a gem but realized that it is just a basic implementation of the oauth.

I configure in devise. rb like this:

```
config.omniauth :mystrategy, 'key', 'secret'
```

Is there an easier way to do this in devise without creating the gem, could I just configure it in a conifg block like

```
    config.omniauth :mystrategy do |strategy|
          strategy.key ='blah'
          strategy.authorize_path = 'blah'
    end
```

Can you show me an example or point me in the right direction?  Everything I saw online was about building it as a strategy gem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've written an oauth strategy from scratch and packaged it as a gem.  If it's just an oauth or oauth2 strategy which you implemented entirely, I don't think you need to do that, or create a gem.  However, I'm not sure there is any way to do it in just a config block.  You should be able to do it by just using https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth or https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2 and creating a subclass with a few methods as described in the READMEs.

I haven't done this myself, but it's the approach taken by other omniauth strategies.  For example, omniauth-twitter is based on the omniauth-oauth strategy as you can see by its superclass:

https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb

omniauth-facebook is based on the omniauth-oauth2 strategy:

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb

Just having your class defined in the Omniauth::Strategies namespace -- e.g. Omniauth::Strategies::Mystrategy should be enough for you to refer to it as :mystrategy in  your omniauth config as mentioned under "Creating a Strategy" here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Strategy-Contribution-Guide